# Negative Binomial Distribution MGF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions, negative-binomial

The Negative Binomial Distribution Wikipedia page lists its Moment-Generation Function as $(\frac{1 - p}{1 - pe^t})^r$.

However, the Moment-Generating Function page lists the MGF of the Negative Binomial Distribution as $(\frac{pe^t}{1 - e^t + pe^t})^r$.

Desmos reveals these not to be algebraically equivalent.  Which one is correct, and why the disparity?

Comment: The roles of $p$ and $q=1-p$ have been somehow flipped. See the text box on the Wikipedia NB page that discusses this inconsistancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to do the case in which $r=1.$

- Let $X$ be the number of independent trials before the first success, with probability $p$ of success on each trial. Then $X\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\Pr(X=x) = (1-p)^x p.$ Then we have $$
  \begin{align}
  M_X(t) & = \operatorname E(e^{tX}) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx} (1-p)^x p \\[8pt]
  & = \frac p {1 - (1-p)e^t} = \frac{1-q}{1-qe^t}.
  \end{align}
  $$
- Now let $X$ be the number of independent trials needed to get one success, with probability $p$ of success on each trial. Then $X\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\Pr(X=x) = (1-p)^{x-1} p.$ Then we have $$
  \begin{align}
  M_X(t) & = \operatorname E(e^{tX}) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx} (1-p)^{x-1} p \\[8pt]
  & = \frac{pe^t}{1 - (1-p)e^t} = \frac{(1-q)e^t}{1 - qe^t}.
  \end{align}
  $$

Thus the one on the MGF page is correct if you consider the "negative binomial distribution" supported on the set $\{r,r+1,r+2,\ldots\},$ and the one on the NB page is correct if you consider the NB distribution supported on the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\},$ and the roles of $p$ and $q$ are interchanged.

Notice that Wikipedia's article titled "Negative binomial distribution" says this:

> Different texts (and even different parts of this article) adopt slightly different definitions for the negative binomial distribution. They can be distinguished by whether the support starts at $k = 0$ or at $k = r,$ whether $p$ denotes the probability of a success or of a failure, and whether $r$ represents success or failure, so it is crucial to identify the specific parametrization used in any given text.